# How to hide the options such as save,undo, in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want these options not to be shown in the top right corner of the title bar as shown in the image below(highlighted)

[image: click here to see the image]

How to hide these options such as run code, save, saves the file, word wrap, etc in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Most of those are from some extension.  Disable them and figure out which ones are doing that and if they have any setting to change it.

Comment: Amazing there’s an extension that does exactly what vscode already does

Comment: VSCode doesn't do that on my machine?

Comment: I disable extensions that worked thank you

Comment: Maybe give a bit of feedback about which extension it was